# How to make two span elements selectable in flex box on double click?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When you double click on one of the two `<span>` elements inside `<div>` you'll select whole word

```html
<div style="display: block;">
  <span>para</span><span>cetamol</span>
</div>
```

But if you'll double click inside flex styled `div` it will select only one word:

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <span>para</span><span>cetamol</span>
</div>
```

How to make two span elements selectable in flex box on double click without js?

[image]

Comment: changing things on click is only possible with js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the css property:

```css
user-select: all
```

so your code should change to:

```html
<div style="display: flex; user-select: all">
  <span>para</span><span>cetamol</span>
</div>
```

Below you have a link to an example:
[JsFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/1bqk8psd/)